# TCP Server on Computer. No connection established

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I have 2 devices on the same network and I want to communicate via TCP on the same network. Device 1 is a computer running a Debian OS on virtualbox, and another is an android tablet. Interesting enough, my tablet acts as a server no problem via an app. Any other device on the same network can connect to the tablet. The computer on the other hand is not so cooperative. Running `netcat -l -p 6667` on my computer should allow incoming connections to communicate with my computer via TCP on port 6667, but this is not the case. Netcat opens a socket but I can't connect to it in anyway. Is there an underlying reason as to why this does not work? All device are under the same router. I have disabled firewall on my computer as well.

Comment: are you trying to get the Debian OS (installed via virtualbox) to act as a server?

Comment: yes I am via Virtualbox, does running the server via Virutalbox change anything?

Comment: "That is not the case" is not a very useful problem description.

Comment: yeah I just ended up using smushi's answer. it works well. I couldn't get the bridge adapter to work though, but I think that is fine. Virtual Box does have a NAT by default which make sense. Thank you smushi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your information, i would say your problem is you need to set up port forward.

VirtualBox and VMware both create virtual machines with the NAT network type by default. If you want to run server software inside a virtual machine, you’ll need to change its network type or forward ports through the virtual NAT.

here is a guide that will show you how to [Forward ports to virtual machine](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/)

Comment: yes, but the router is seeing his actual computer port and not the port of virtual OS